# Simulation of mobile base in gazebo is not visualizing in rviz

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, mobile-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I loaded a mobile base with differential drive in gazebo and I am able to control it in teleop mode. I tried to connect visualization to rviz. The robot is loaded fine in rviz . Wheels are rotating , but robot is not moving. Can any explain the reason?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199155/simulation-of-mobile-base-in-gazebo-is-not-visualizing-in-rviz/) by [SVS](https://answers.ros.org/users/19399/svs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 233 on 2014-12-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rviz Global Options | Fixed Frame is set to base_link or the equivalent for your robot?  If you set it to map and then don't see the robot properly then there needs to be something that publishes a transform between map and base_link.

You can 'cheat' and get the position from /gazebo/model_states and then publish it as a transform.  The more realistic thing to do is implement odometry and have that publish the transform from there, though it will deviate from gazebo absolute position after a while (just as it would in real life).

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2014-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SVS](https://answers.ros.org/users/19399/svs/) on 2014-12-10**:
I used differential drive plugin of gazebo.Inside that,there  is odometry tag which publishes odom and it is publishing also.That odom topic can be selected from rviz without any errors. But it is not updating.

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2014-12-12**:
There is a package called [gazebo2rviz](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo2rviz). May be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given tele-operatable somehow on `Gazebo`, I assume your robot is equipped with a contoroller. Since RViz wants `joint_state` topic to update the robot's external status, you might want to implement `JointStateController`-equivalent on your controller's end. If you use [ros_control](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control), [this thread](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4205/joint_state-ros-topic-from-gazebo-and-ros_control/) elaborates well.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-12-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of your "base_link"?
If the name is "world" renaming it might help, that how I solved this problem

My thinking is, by naming your base_link "world" gazebo will interpreter it as its world frame therefore rendering objects attached to it immovable, and for your case that is the reason the robot does not move though the wheels rotate